# Is there any way stop execution of current running WorkManager task?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

**WorkManager API Android**

I have written WorkManager code to perform some work in background. 

It is OneTimeRequestBuilder. I want to cancel execution of running WorkManager task.

I tried canceling WorkManager with following code

```
WorkManager.getInstance().cancelWorkById(workId)
```

I tried another method **cancelAllWorkByTag** function , even this has not worked.

As per documentation

> Cancels all unfinished work with the given tag. Note that cancellation is a best-effort policy and work that is already executing may continue to run.

Best-effort policy does not cancel current executing work.

**Is there any way to force stop current execution ?**

*P.S. Can not share code*

Comment: are you passing the same `tag` which is used to initiate `executor(tag)`.`WorkManager` is guaranteed API for background works. This must not be its behavior. And also check if you are using the same `instance` of `WorkManager`.

Comment: Yes I am using same instance of WorkManager , and same tag which used at executor.

Comment: Have your ongoing work monitor some application state that determines whether or not it should stop. This could be as simple as some `boolean`. Since the documentation indicates that it will not guarantee stopping already-executing work, you will need to do that yourself.